# Sherlock option menu item does not respond

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

The is a problem that affects platforms prior to 3.0, i.e. when Sherlock acts as a proxy to provide the action bar menu items.

I have a Fragment Activity that contains two fragments, each with its own set of options menus.  When the activity starts the first fragment tab is shown and its menu items work normally.  However, the first time that I switch to the other tab its menu items do not respond.  If I switch back to the first tab and select the other tab again they start to fire normally.

It looks like this is a known problem.  Check out the discussion [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/521).

My workaround for now is to detect the first time that the second tab is selected and programatically switch back to the first tab.  This forces the user to select the second tab again, but from that point on it works normally, as long as the user stays in that activity.

I am wondering if anyone else has found a more elegant solution to this problem.  Thanks!

First fragment:

```
  @Override
      public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      moveMenuItem   = menu.add(Flashum.MENU_GROUP_MULTI, Flashum.MOVE_FLASHES_ID, 0, R.string.move_flashes);
      cloneMenuItem  = menu.add(Flashum.MENU_GROUP_MULTI, Flashum.CLONE_FLASHES_ID, 0, R.string.clone_flashes);
      deleteMenuItem = menu.add(Flashum.MENU_GROUP_MULTI, Flashum.DELETE_FLASHES_ID, 0, R.string.delete_flashes);
      moveMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
      moveMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.move2red);
      cloneMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
      cloneMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.hard_drive_clone);
      deleteMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
      deleteMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);
   }
```

Second fragment:

```
   @Override
      public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      saveMenuItem = menu.add(Flashum.MENU_GROUP_SAVE, Flashum.SAVE_CHANGES_ID, 0, R.string.save_changes);
      saveMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
      saveMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.save);
      menu.setGroupVisible(Flashum.MENU_GROUP_SAVE, true);

      recMenuItem = menu.add(Flashum.MENU_GROUP_REC, Flashum.RECORD_ID, 0, R.string.record);
      recMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
      recMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.microphonehot);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear your menu before you inflate it in your fragments. So in your fragments in onCreateOptionsMenu methods call menu.clear(); at the beginning and then inflate your menu.
Something like this:

```
   @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater); 
  menu.clear();

  saveMenuItem = menu.add(Flashum.MENU_GROUP_SAVE, Flashum.SAVE_CHANGES_ID, 0, R.string.save_changes);
  saveMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  saveMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.save);
  menu.setGroupVisible(Flashum.MENU_GROUP_SAVE, true);

  recMenuItem = menu.add(Flashum.MENU_GROUP_REC, Flashum.RECORD_ID, 0, R.string.record);
  recMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  recMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.microphonehot);
```

}

Try it in both of your fragments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it makes no difference.

Comment: Interesting... I had similar problem with menu item and it worked for me. 
You can try one more thing, add super() call to your onCreateOptionsMenu() before menu.clear();
Like this:
     @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater    inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    //rest of creating menu
    }

Try to do it in both of your fragments.
And let's hope that Jake will fix this soon if it will not work.

Regards :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

As far as i know when you call super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater); in your fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu() it calls onCreateOptionsMenu() in your activity and then in all fragments in backStack which have set setHasOptionsMenu() to true. So for all fragments you are clearing menu and then adding items to it. I don't exactly know why it works but it's quite simple solution :)

Comment: And when you initially answered my question you had a reputation of exactly 1.  Now after 1 day it is 91 so you have been busy!  I remember it took me weeks to get to where you are at.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detecting when the second tab is selected, switch the fragments programmatically in the onCreate of your Activity using a post delayed method. For example I have 3 fragments and I switch them in reverse order (2, 1, 0) and it fools your users with a nice animation at the beginning of the Activity:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
  mIndicator.setCurrentItem(2);
  mIndicator.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
  mIndicator.setCurrentItem(1);
  mIndicator.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      mIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);
  }}, 100);
}}, 100);
}
```